# Standalone Install PHP on IIS

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, windows-7-x64

I use IIS7 and Windows7 ultimate, and I need to install PHP on IIS in this machine, but the problem is I don't have any internet access in this computer, so the first step is search on standalone version, the result is nothing, then I try to install PHP on another machine (with internet access) and copy `AppData` files to target machine. So I install successfully in first machine and copy all the `Web Platform Installer` folder from `AppData` to target machine, but unfortunately  the installation failed and need to connect to internet.

So how can I install PHP on IIS without internet access?
I also have `Web Platform Installer` folder from first machine? does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the php for windows executables somewhere on your PC? If yes then you can simply goto to IIS
Add Managed Handler
and add 
*.php as the Request Path
Module : FastCgiModule
Executable :
F:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe
and restart IIS.

This should do it for you.

Comment: But I don't Have CGiModule Type, How Can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add

This is a guide how to add an handler, but uses php as its example